# build projects from Github Makefile

Tags: assembly, makefile

I have downloaded a game called (MineAssemble it's a clone of minecraft) from Github (https://github.com/Overv/MineAssemble) written in assembly for x86 processer
so i want to boot it from my bios or Qemu(cpu emulator).
there is only source assembly code in Github so i must build the game from scratch.
the project contain a Makefile and I've tried to run it by using "Mingw32-make" but when i run "Make" in cmd without any arguments i get this:

```
C:\Users\sw\Downloads\MineAssemble-master\make

i686-pc-elf-gcc -std=c99 -MMD -m32 -g -ggdb -O3 -ffast-math -ffreestanding -nostdlib -nostdinc  -fno-builtin -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -fno-exceptions -fno-stack-protector -static -fno-pic   -c -o src/reference.o src/reference.c
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, i686-pc-elf-gcc -std=c99 -MMD -m32 -g -ggdb -O3 -ffast-math -ffreestanding -nostdlib -nostdinc -fno-builtin -nostartfiles -no defaultlibs -fno-exceptions -fno-stack-protector -static -fno-pic -c -o src/reference.o src/reference.c, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'src/reference.o' failed
make: *** [src/reference.o] Error 2
```

I have NASM assembler and ld linker.

what is wrong? what is the solution?

Comment: This is not written in assembly, or at least not entirely in assembly: the file you're trying to compile ends in ".c" which means it's a C file not an assembly file (maybe it has lots of assembly in it).  You need to install a C compiler (in this case it seems to assume your compiler is named "i686-pc-elf-gcc") to build this code.

Comment: I have gcc compiler and the project owner said I just need to run "make" to build.

Comment: The game is written in assembly and there is separately c version inside the project.

Comment: Well, you clearly don't have the C compiler that the makefile is expecting, because that error message means that the compiler can't be found.  If you run `i686-pc-elf-gcc` from your command prompt you will get a "not found" error.

Comment: please visit this link (https://github.com/Overv/MineAssemble) the game is written in assembly i want to build it to boot it from my computer.

Comment: You should file an issue at that GitHub project and ask for help there: https://github.com/Overv/MineAssemble/issues  StackOverflow is good for getting answers to clear questions about a specific programming problems.  It's not good at providing general support for other software.